# Why does page extend all the way across the screen?

Tags: html, css

I set the width of my page to a certain size.  Some pages follow this like the home page: http://www.problemio.com but for some reason, other pages just extend the entire width like this page: http://www.problemio.com/community/public_member_profile.php?member_id=1

I don't see any difference between them in firebug.  Does anyone else understand why the pages have different width?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first link is constrained by the parent div

`<div class="container">`

The second link is not as the container element does not exist.